# When trying to download the latest version of android studio I am getting this message

Tags: android-studio, download

After agreeing the terms and condition to download android studio I get this message:

[image: After agreeing the terms and condition to download android studio I get this message.]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you got to that point.
https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html#downloads

Use the IDE verion:
https://dl.google.com/dl/android/studio/ide-zips/2.1.1.0/android-studio-ide-143.2821654-linux.zip

Answer (score 0):

Problem is Solved.

I tried downloading it with Chromium and it downloaded and is working.
I don't know why it was not downloading in firefox.